# Mock attribute of a class

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I'm doing an unit test on a file and I'm having trouble to mock an attribute or function call (`self.logger.info`) in my class B. I have two classes A and B and B inherit from A.

```
import logging

class A(object): 
    def __init__(self):
        self.logger = logging.getLogger()
```

and in another module:

```
from A import A

class B(A):  
    def function(self):
        self.logger.info("Hello")
```

I want to mock `self.logger.info` to not be called. I tried to used `patch('A.logging.info')` but it didn't work. I also tried `patch('A.logging.getLogger')` but if I `print type(self.logger)` in `function()` while testing I get an logging object not a mock object.

Comment: I removed the `B.__init__()` method because a) it was redundant without doing anything itself, and b) your `super()` call was invalid (use `super(B, self)`, not `super(A, self)`).

Comment: sorry for the mistakes i tried to do a quick example which was representing my actual code.

Comment: Be *careful* when producing a new example, in that it still should *reproduce the problem you have*. Test the code you post first to see that you haven't accidentally removed the source of your issue. Oh, and that it actually *works*.

Comment: Also see [mcve] in the help center.

Comment: Ok the issue was that I was creating a object to test in all my unit tests and as i added the logging patch after the object was created it couldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Your attribute is set *when creating an instance*. Just patch `logging.getLogger` or even `logging.Logger.info`.

If you patch the `logging.getLogger()` call, you don't have to patch any other `self.logger` calls either, as the resulting mock will take care of any attributes on it:

```
with mock.patch('logging.getLogger') as mock_log:
    mock_logger = mock_log.return_value
    b = B()
    b.function()
    mock_logger.info.assert_called_with('Hello')
```

With the mock in place, using `logging.getLogger()` returns a new mock object (the [`mock_log.return_value` object](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.return_value)), and any attempt to access `self.logger.info` then returns the `mock_log.return_value.info` object, which logs calls testable with the [`Mock.assert_called_with()` method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html#unittest.mock.Mock.assert_called_with).

Demo:

```
>>> import mock
>>> import logging
>>> class A(object): 
...     def __init__(self):
...         self.logger = logging.getLogger()
... 
>>> class B(A):
...     def function(self):
...         self.logger.info("Hello")
... 
>>> with mock.patch('logging.getLogger') as mock_log:
...     mock_logger = mock_log.return_value
...     b = B()
...     b.function()
...     mock_logger.info.assert_called_with('Hello')
... 
>>> mock_logger
<MagicMock name='getLogger()' id='4375059984'>
>>> mock_logger.info
<MagicMock name='getLogger().info' id='4374917008'>
>>> mock_logger.info.call_args
call('Hello')
```

Comment: I tried already to patch only logging.getLogger but it's not working. If I do a patch(A.logging.getLogger) and do a print type(self.logger) i still get a logging object not a mock object. class A and B are in different files.

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale: then *show that in your question*. Include how it is not working for you (as in, tell us what actually happens and what you expected to happen instead).

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale: note that I told you to patch `logging.getLogger`, **not** `A.logging.getLogger`.

Comment: @RomanzoCriminale: no, `mock.patch()` takes care of handling that for you.

Comment: I'm trying to update my example because i can't make it work even with your help

Answer (score 0):

The real issue is that you want to patch **just** `info` logger and not logger. To do it you should use

```
patch.object(logging.getlogger(), 'info')

>>> from mock import patch
>>> with patch.object(logging.getLogger(), "info") as mock_info:
...     B().function()
...     print(mock_info.mock_calls)
...     mock_info.assert_called_with("Hello")
[call('Hello')]
```

The funny thing is that `logging.getLogger()` return a global object a so this method work even if `B` object is created before the patch context:

```
>>> b = B()
>>> with patch.object(logging.getLogger(), "info") as mock_info:
...     b.function()
...     print(mock_info.mock_calls)
...     mock_info.assert_called_with("Hello")
... 
[call('Hello')]
```